# benchmarking agents using pybrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, pybrain

I have recently started coding my own agents in python(not using pybrain library) and it has come to the point where I would like to start running some proper benchmarking. I would like to run on a few mazes, pole balancing and mountain car.

I am aware of PyBrain having these environments already coded, is it possible to interact with those environments by connecting it to my own code using some sort of bridge/interface? I saw something like RLGlue bridge but the state of it seems questionable.

Has anyone successfully used the PyBrain environments already with a different bridge? I suppose the easiest solution would be to just adapt my code to the format of PyBrain agent and forgo bridging... but i'd like to save time by just connecting the two.

Thanks